# HTTP2 requests with 1 concurrent stream

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, delay, http2, nghttp2

Just  to confirm. I have a simple http2 server which answers after 1 second, so  forces a 1-second delay for every incoming request.

Facts:
Using h2load with single concurrent stream (-m 1), I have 1 req/second.

So, even freeing the tatsuhiro nghttp2 io service by mean scheduling the 1-second delay asynchronously, no new requests will be sent until the request on-the-fly is answered.

Is it the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Yes its expected. In HTTP/2 each request is sent on a unique stream id. You’ve told h2load to only have one stream going at a time, so that’s what it’s doing.

Comment: Thank you Barry, I thought that my implementation could have a bottleneck, but not.